# Toggle Switch on Datatables using Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I am trying to add a column for a toggle switch in my data table, but it's not working. It's just showing this text

[image: Image 1]

When it should be like this

[image: Image 2]

These are my codes

```
$(function(){
    $('#table').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: '{!! URL::asset('/amenity/table') !!}',
      columns : [
        { data: function (data) {return '<a href="amenity-details?id=' + data.id + '">' + data.name + '</a>';}, name: 'name' },
        { data: 'dayrate', name: 'dayrate' },
        { data: 'nightrate', name: 'nightrate' },
        { data: function(data){
            return '<div class="switch switch-square" data-on-label=\"<i class=" fa fa-check"></i>\" data-off-label=\"<i class="fa fa-times"></i>\"> <input type="checkbox" class="status '+data.status+'" data-id="'+data.id+'" /></div>';
        }, name: 'state', orderable: true, searchable: false},
        { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
      ]

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

#### CAUSE

Since your switch is added at later time after `ready` event, it doesn't get initialized.

#### SOLUTION

You need to initialize controls used in jQuery DataTable each time the table is redrawn. Use [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option to define a function that will be called every time the table has been redrawn.

For example:

```js
$('#table').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
   drawCallback: function(settings){
      var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );

      // Initialize switch
      $('.switch', api.table().body()).bootstrapSwitch(); 
   }
});
```

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Custom control does not work on second page and after](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-custom-control-does-not-work-on-second-page/) for more examples and details.

Comment: I tried this, and the table doesn't show anymore :(

Comment: @user5156944, try to include only `drawCallback` part.